# Plain UITableView with Grouped cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITableView with headers that behave like a Plain UITableView (i.e. the float at the top until they are displaced by the next header and so on...

But the cells themselves will have a Grouped look to them.

I've set the TableViewStyle to UITableViewStylePlain to get the correct behaviour of the header.

Now, I'm thinking my only option is to create images to use as the background of my own custom cells.

I will need a top, bottom, middle and single image that will have rounded corners to cover all the possibilities.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already wrote option A). You can also go the opposite way (without the need of images, but some more logic):

1. Use `UITableViewStyleGrouped`
2. Add one floating header view as a seperate view on top of the tableView
3. Set the `UITableViewDelegate`
4. Setup the header views via the delegate
5. Use `scrollViewDidScroll:` (the tableView delegate also delegates the scrollViewDelegate) and check which section is the top most section currently, update the floating header to its contents and update the position of the floating header to `scrollView.contentOffset`

Comment: Hmm... I like the sound of doing that. I also get to write my own dequeuing class which sounds fun :D I might give that a go, thanks.

Comment: OK, I've started this now and it's working so far. I thought of a slightly different way though. All I need is one floating header at a time. So I have a floating header that I can reuse. Then intercepting the scroll view movement I can determine where we are in the table view and draw the floating accordingly. Will blog my solution when I'm done, I like this :D

Comment: Right! I've done it this way and it works and the scrolling is perfectly smooth (something I worried about with having images all over etc...) Will post the code as it was a pain to get right.

Comment: sounds great, please post the link here, when its online. but you need as many headers, as there can be headers visible at once, right? e.g. if you have 4 sections with just one row, you'll need at least 4 headers to display at once.

Comment: You still display the headers. Just use an additional "floating header". My headers aren't transparent so not a problem. Will see if I can get around transparent headers too.

Comment: I updated my answer, so other readers will find the better solution directly.